# Overfitting SVM with Gaussian Kernel

Tags: machine-learning, svm, matlab

It seems that I'm having a bit of an overfitting problem. I've tried playing around a lot with my SVM (rather, MATLAB's `fitcsvm`), and I'm not sure how to fix it.

From my knowledge, Gaussian kernels have two basic parameters: sigma ('KernelScale' in MATLAB) and C (~1/'BoxConstrant' in MATLAB). I've tried to optimize these with no avail. My training sets are EEG signals that are 125 indices long, and my training size is about 2000 observations. I'm doing multiclass classification, with three classes in all, each with about equal in size.

I've tried to optimize using fminsearch to minimize the 10-fold cross validation loss of my SVM, starting at various initial conditions. For example, right now my [BoxConstraint, KernelScale] are in "z" in the following code, which creates a grid from 10^-3 to 10^3.

```
y = logspace(-3,3,6);
meshgrid(y);
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(y);
z = [xx(:),yy(:)];
```

All of these values result in my k-fold losses in the three SVM models created for my multiclass classification:

```
0.3318
0.2724
0.3959
```

I have also had larger BoxConstraints, to no avail. For one of my SVM models, for example:

```
 |-------------|---------------|-----------| 

 | KernelScale | BoxConstraint | KfoldLoss | 

 | 1.001001    | 1.001001      | 0.331762  | 

 | 1.001001    | 1.010050      | 0.331762  | 

 | 1.001001    | 1.105171      | 0.331762  | 

 | 1.001001    | 2.718282      | 0.331762  | 

 | 1.001001    | 22026.47      | 0.331762  | 

 | 1.001001    | 2.69E+43      | 0.331762  |
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong? I don't understand how a BoxConstraint of 2.69E+43 (as seen in the last row of the above table) could possibly still have overfitting.

Comment: What makes you think that you're overfitting? All I see here is that your accuracies aren't perfect, but that could just as easily be underfitting, or that you've actually reached the best possible RBF-SVM model for this dataset and it's just not perfect.

Comment: One thing you are doing "wrong," it seems, is that you're only doing one level of CV, which means that your kernel bandwidth / C choices can overfit to the dataset. It's slower, but to get more reliable estimates you should do an "outer" CV to pick train/test sets, run an "inner" CV to pick hyperparameters *only on that train set*, and then evaluate them on the test set.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not so sure I understand.  I currently have my data separated into two groups - a training/CV group (80%) and a testing group (20%). I was under the impression that my 10-fold cross validation of the 80% training/CV group would be the inner set in your description, and my testing set would be the outer one? But it seems that I'm wrong in interpreting you.

Another interesting thing is that I think two of my data sets should be distinguishable, because the average of the FFTs of two of the three sets are visually distinguishable (though admittedly not by much).

Comment: Yes, that's okay too; I didn't get that you had a separate testing set from your question.  The only risk there is in overfitting to the training set by running repeatedly on that, but the CV itself won't do that, just if you try a bunch of variants on the CV parameters and pick the best one.

Comment: Hi - thanks again. But so the reason why I'm confused is because the data seems to be overfitting regardless of how high I make my BoxConstraint. One would expect that setting a BoxConstraint to absurdly high would prevent overtraining. One could tell if the SVM is overtrained by looking at the error in the classification of the training data itself. However, I'm consistently getting 0 error in my training data, e.g. no misclassifications. I've tried BoxConstraints as high as 10e60, and as low as 1e-6, but my SVM still seems to use have every input dataset as a support vector. 

Any ideas?

Comment: My code, by the way, is simply:


`SVMModels{j} = fitcsvm(training_bins,indx,'ClassNames',[false true],'Standardize',true,'KernelFunction','rbf','BoxConstraint',minimization_params(j,2), 'KernelScale',minimization_params(j,1) ); 
`

Is there something stupid I've done above?

Comment: What's the median Euclidean distance between input vectors after standardizing? If it ends up being quite large, you may not be trying large enough `KernelScale`s – I notice that the ones you listed above all used scale 1, which is likely to be much too small for 125-dimensional standardized inputs, and could lead to the problem you're seeing.

Comment: I hate to sound like a broken record, but again, thanks again.

To be honest, I'm not sure how to implement standardization of input vectors and to find their Euclidean distance. However, when I changed my scaling factor to 1e4, I got misclassifications of my training data. So it seems then that I should search through (Scale, BoxConstraint) pairs that have larger Scale than what I've been setting so far, perhaps with Scale ranging from 1e2 to 1e6 or so?

But hmm, after standardizing, the Eucalidean distance can still be large? Interesting. Should I still standardize, or perhaps abandon that?

Comment: Yep, that's worth a try at least.